# DataTable Get Value of a Row under a Column Value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a `DataTable` in C#, and I would like to loop through each row of a particular column with the title specified.

Below is my code snippet:

```
foreach (DataRow listing in dtAll.Rows)
{
    //get the value of <ID> column for each row
    int itemID = ["ID"].value;
}
```

May I know how can it be done? Thank you.

Comment: First thing *I* would do is rush to the documentation and see if there were any useful properties for [`DataRow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarow?view=netframework-4.8) or perhaps methods I could use to get a column value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        foreach (DataRow listing in dtAll.Rows)
        {
            int itemID = listing.Field<int>("ID");
        }
```

but note comments above as a search would probably have saved you posting